# Foreign key validation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I am trying to design a database with a 1 to many relationship where 1 parent can have many children. The database seems to work OK.  I am trying to write integration tests to check for invalid data and that works OK, but it fails when I try inputting valid data into the database.  It gives me a similar error to below.  Am I doing something wrong in my code, or could it be a problem with my test?

**When I output the child.errors**

```
.F........#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fe0fccb50b8 @base=#<Play id: nil, ad_id: 42, duration: 8, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:ad=>["can't be blank"]}>
.#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fe0fa5756d8 @base=#<Play id: nil, ad_id: 2, duration: 8, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:ad=>["can't be blank"]}>
```

**Integration Test**

```
def setup
    Ad.create!(ad_id: 2, device_id: 1, user_id: 1, cost:300.20, title: 'my awesome ad')
    Ad.create!(ad_id: 3, device_id: 2, user_id: 3, cost:40, title: 'super')
    Ad.create!(ad_id: 1, device_id: 1, user_id: 2, cost:500, title: 'my awesome ad')
    Ad.create!(ad_id: 4, device_id: 2, user_id: 2, cost:500, title: 'super')
end
test 'log a valid play' do
  post '/plays',      
      play: {
             ad_id: 2,
             duration: 8
           }
         }
    assert_equal 201, response.status
  end
```

**Failed Test**

```
  1) Failure:
    LogPlayTest#test_log_a_valid_play [/path/log_play_test.rb:18]:
    Expected: 201
    Actual: 422
```

**Child Migration**

```
class CreatePlays < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :plays do |t|
      t.integer :ad_id
      t.integer :duration

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :plays, :ad_id
  end
end
```

**Parent Migration**

```
class CreateAds < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :ads do |t|
      t.integer :ad_id
      t.integer :device_id
      t.integer :user_id
      t.float :cost
      t.string :title

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :ads, :ad_id
  end
end
```

**Parent Model**

```
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :plays
end
```

**Child Model**

```
class Play < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ad
  validates :ad, presence: true
end
```

**Child Controller**

```
def create
    play = Play.new(play_params)
    if play.save
      p play.save 
      render nothing:true, status: 201, location: play
    else
      p play.errors #the output is shown above
      render json: play.errors, status: 422
    end
  end
```

Comment: I don't think this code is representative because the parent test you've provided appears to be showing an error message for a child model validation.

Comment: I will edit my post to show actual code.

Comment: It would also be helpful to see how instances are being created in your tests.

Comment: I edited my post to show my actual code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say the issue is with foreign keys. When you put test Ads in the database, you are giving each an ad_id:

```
Ad.create!(ad_id: 2...)
```

I'm not totally sure what you're doing there, but if that's meant to be a primary key, I'd recommend following convention and using the id that Rails generates for you automatically. For example:

```
Ad.first.id == 1
```

A play that is related to an ad stores this primary key as it's foreign key:

```
Play.first.ad_id == 1
```

Therefore:

```
Play.ad.id == 1
```

It appears that you are trying to use a custom foreign key without telling Rails what you are doing, which is why the parent ad isn't found. Your two choices are two follow convention or override the foreign key. Read about overriding here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference

### Clarification

If you choose to follow convention, just remove the ad_id attribute from the ads table and use the id instead. You can build associations to set the foreign key automatically like this:

```
@ad.plays.new()
```

If you want to override the foreign key, try:

```
class Play < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ad, foreign_key: "ad_id"
end
```

Read more about overriding in the documentation linked above.

Comment: I will probably try and override the foreign key because I am getting the foreign key from another place, and I need to store that information in the database.  Thank you this is really helpful.  Can you show how to override the foreign key?  That's where I get confused.

Comment: Thank you!  I am curious as to why `"ad_id"` would be in quotes.  Not `:ad_id`?  Would there be a difference?

Comment: It will probably work either way - you'll have to try it out. I use quotes because that's how it's done in the Rails docs.

Comment: I changed my code and I am still getting the same error. ` .......#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007ffe3888bfb0 @base=#<Play id: nil, ad_id: 2, duration: 8, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:ad=>["can't be blank"]}>
F#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007ffe3473fc00 @base=#<Play id: nil, ad_id: 42, duration: 8, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:ad=>["can't be blank"]}>
...F

Finished in 0.320290s, 37.4660 runs/s, 81.1764 assertions/s.

  1) Failure:
LogPlayTest#test_log_a_valid_play [...]:
Expected: 201
  Actual: 422`

Comment: Could it be that my class Play is singular not plural? `class Play < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ad, foreign_key: "ad_id"
  validates :ad, presence: true
end
`

Comment: No, that should def be singular

Comment: Could there be an issue where I chose my foreign key to be ad_id when it already defaults to ad_id? Is there a way I could distinguish? Should I just call ad_id something else?